# Format body of email using SkpsmtpMessage library

Tags: ios

I am using SkpsmtpMessage library into my project and everything works good. 
Problem is with layout of body of email. I want to show it in nice layout like bold name then want to embed image into it so that it would show when client open email etc etc. 
Right now i am just using

```
NSString * bodyMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Dear %@:\n \nThank you for reserving your holiday  with us. Your order is now confirmed - 
see below your details including your order reference number and your chosen collection point. ",%@];
```

Its just demonstration. 
So how could i properly format it like we do in other email clients.

Thank you in advance.

SOLUTION:

Use

```
 NSDictionary *plainPart = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"text/html",kSKPSMTPPartContentTypeKey,
                           body ,kSKPSMTPPartMessageKey,@"8bit",kSKPSMTPPartContentTransferEncodingKey,nil];
```

i.e text/html instead of text/plain.

code is

```
SKPSMTPMessage  *testMsg = [[SKPSMTPMessage alloc] init];
NSDictionary *plainPart = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"text/html",kSKPSMTPPartContentTypeKey,
                           body ,kSKPSMTPPartMessageKey,@"8bit",kSKPSMTPPartContentTransferEncodingKey,nil];
testMsg.parts = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:plainPart,nil];

[testMsg send];
```

here body is NSString containing html text...

Thank you. Hope anyone else could use it.

Comment: Thanks a lot ... I was about to waste my time .....

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for the class itself says:

> SKPSMTPMessage is a quick and dirty class which implements a basic SMTP client for the iPhone. If you just want to post a plain text or HTML message on the iPhone, use -[UIApplication openURL:] (these are not the droids you're looking for, move along, move along). However, if you're trying to attach a file to an email, or do other crazy stuff, you'll want to use this class.

Also, it was last updated in February 2009, over 3 years ago.

Although not a direct answer to your question - a better solution is to not use this framework.

Comment: Is there any other alternative of SKPSMTPMessage? where i could post html message and embed picture?

Comment: Abizern check solution mate... Sorted now. thanks for your reply anyway